# PostgreSQL Exception : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services

*I know it is a duplicate question . But I couldn't find solution for the same.*

I have hosted my application in the Amazon EC2 cloud. 
And I am using postgresql .

I am getting an exception `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.` while running my application in **[Amazon cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/)**.

The detailed stack-trace is :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:281)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:403)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:331)
    at com.spy2k3.core.business.processor.ProcessorImpl.executeUpdate(ProcessorImpl.java:237)
    at com.spy2k3.core.business.object.BusinessObject.executeUpdate(BusinessObject.java:54)
    at com.spy2k3.core.business.object.LoginObject.deleteSession(LoginObject.java:127)
    at com.spy2k3.core.business.processor.LoginProcessor.userValidation(LoginProcessor.java:79)
    at com.spy2k3.core.business.processor.LoginProcessor.execute(LoginProcessor.java:30)
    at com.spy2k3.core.business.processor.ProcessorImpl.process(ProcessorImpl.java:73)
    at com.spy2k3.core.handler.request.RequestHandler.doService(RequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.spy2k3.core.handler.AbstractHandler.doPost(AbstractHandler.java:25)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:112)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:71)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:269)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1700)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    ... 37 more
```

**Tests :**

**1**.I connected my remote postgresql server via PgAdmin from my local system , and I could connect and execute queries.

**2**.I connected to my remote server via putty , and could successfully execute queries.
    EXAMPLE :

> ```
>     [root@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx bin]# psql -U myuser -d mydatabase
>     psql (9.2.4)
>     Type "help" for help.
>
> mydatabase=# SELECT USERID FROM MY_MAST_LOGINSESSION WHERE SESSIONID='5DFD5D1E09D523695D6057SOMETHING';
>  userid
> --------
> (0 rows)
> ```

**3**.When I connected my remote database via jdbc from my application , it successfully connected , but it is taking too much time to execute the queries there.

Can you suggest any solution to find out this time delay ?

**UPDATE :**

During going deep into the problem , I found the delay happens only for specific queries such as `DELETE` , `UPDATE` . The queries such as `INSERT` ,`SELECT` executes fine .

The specialty of `DELETE` and  `UPDATE`queries are which return nothing .

So the actual problem is the querying client (suppose `psql`) is waiting for the Database server response , but for these queries server returns nothing . So the client keeps on waiting and after the timeout it throws exception .

But I was unable to find where to change to solve this problem.

Comment: Look at the **PostgreSQL server error log** on your server, see what it is saying about the disconnections. Personally I'd say you've got connectivity problems, given the delays and intermittent disconnections.

Comment: Can you post your connection string without your server's ip and username/pass and the method which queries the database?

Comment: @CraigRinger ,Arya : I updated my question .

Comment: Bizarre theory re delete/update vs insert/select. The server still returns a rowcount and sqlstate for these commands. Keep looking, that's unlikely to be the problem. If you're stuck use something like Wireshark to examine the network communication in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with the `synchronous_standby_names` parameter in `postgresql.conf`.

In my `postgresql.conf`, it was `synchronous_standby_names = '*'`.

When I commented out the line, I was able to execute all queries.

From the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-replication.html):

> **synchronous_standby_names (string)** : At any one time there will be at most one
>   active synchronous standby; transactions waiting for commit will be
>   allowed to proceed after this standby server confirms receipt of their
>   data.
>
> **.  . .**
>
> If no synchronous standby names are specified here, **then synchronous
>   replication is not enabled and transaction commits will not wait for
>   replication**.

So the actual problem was:
The querying client (suppose psql) was waiting for the Database server response, but for these queries the server returns nothing since **synchronous replication was enabled**. So the client kept on waiting and after the timeout it threw an exception.